# Using Batch Scripting in HTML

Tags: html, batch-file

I've been doing batch scripting for a while now, and more recently I've been experimenting with HTML webpages, and I'm wondering: can I execute batch files within the HTML webpage? The way I understand it, the  tag can be used for things such as JavaScript, C# or C++, to incorporate the script into the webpage. I tried "  ", and the rest of the script, but this either didn't work or brought no observable results.

So really what I'm wondering is: is there a tag for batch scripting in HTML files (and if so, how or where can I learn more about this) or am I better off learning one of the above languages.

Edit: Okay, so say I wan't to make a webpage with some kind of converter in it. Can I use the < input > tag to note that use the input as the variable to be converted, run this through an equation using the < script > tag, and display the final value in the webpage itself? If so, is there a tag to do this using batch language syntax?

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking. But HTML is a `markup` language, it doesn't *run* anything

Comment: You can make a web-browser load and execute something like a media player, when you are linking local media files, but you can't launch a batch file or executable.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough... more in the edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You theoretically could implement server-side web pages that call out to Windows batch files.  But it would be really clumsy, poorly performing, and probably insecure.  Almost any other language would be better, which is probably why you've never heard of it being done yet.

There are systems like ASP.NET, PHP, JSP, etc. that allow you to implement custom processing on the server based on user requests.

Or, you could use JavaScript in the page to run your code on the user's own computer, in the browser.  For simple purposes, or highly interactive purposes, or if you don't have a server with server-side scripting support, implementing your functionality in JavaScript is a great way to do it.  You can do almost anything in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, that bit about JavaScript is along the lines of what I was thinking. From what I understand, JavaScript is supported by all major browsers (meaning I wouldn't have to download any software)?